# Prove that two norms are not equivalent in $l_2$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that the norm $$|||(x_n)|||=\sum_ {n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}|x_n|$$ is not
equivalent to the norm $||·||_2$ in $l_2$ space.

What can you say about this norm in other spaces of successions?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to prove the non-equivalence of these norms.

Comment: @CarmenMaria - please include in your question what are your thoughts, why do you think they are non-equivalent, what have you tried, where is the difficulty. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? Here is a hint : find a sequence of elements of $l_2$, say $\left({x_n}^m \right)$ such that $|||x^m||| = 1$ but $\|x^m\|\to \infty$ with $m$.

Comment: I have tried to find that sequence of elements so that it converges in one norm and not in the other but I have not been able to find it. I have tried that way without success and by defining equivalent norms trying to find constants that do not satisfy but this path did not seem appropriate. So I think my more concise question is what succession does the property mentioned above verify?

Comment: From DIdier’s comment if you take $$x_n^m:=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll} 1&\mbox{if $n\le m$}\\0&\mbox{if otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ what can you say about the vectors $(x_n^m)_n$ in both norms as $m\to\infty$?

Comment: Ok, I think that I understand you. Thanks